# Using Pug (Jade) with Jinja2 tempting syntax

Tags: python, gruntjs, pug, jinja2

I use grunt with Pug (Jade) to render my HTML templates.
I want to incorporate Jinja2 syntax in my Pug files but when I run grunt to build the HTML files it fails because it does not recognize the Jinja2 syntax.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Not possible. I would suggest looking at the pug equivalents for those statements.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at: https://github.com/kakulukia/pypugjs ?

Seems to support Jinja2:

```
jinja_env = Environment(extensions=['pypugjs.ext.jinja.PyPugJSExtension'])
```

The below pug (jade) code example

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
    script(type='text/javascript').
      if (foo) {
         bar()
      }
  body
    h1.title PugJS - node template engine
    #container
      if youAreUsingPugJS
        p You are amazing
      else
        p Get on it!
```

gets converted to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>{{pageTitle}}</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      if (foo) {
         bar()
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="title">PugJS - node template engine</h1>
    <div id="container">
      {%if youAreUsingPugJS%}
        <p>You are amazing</p>
      {%else%}
        <p>Get on it!</p>
      {%endif%}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can use following utility command to do it:

```
pypugjs -c jinja input.pug output.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I basically wrote [a whole library](https://github.com/knowsuchagency/ninjadog) so that I could do exactly the same thing,
particularly as a renderer in [Pyramid](https://trypyramid.com/)